# Get element width in px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to get element width in pixels (px)? jQuery always returns value in percent (pct).

**HTML**

```
<span class="myElement"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.myElement {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('span.myElement').css('width') // returns '100%'
$('span.myElement').width() // returns '100'
```

Thanks!

Comment: `width()` should be what you want. If it's not working, it's probably because you're using a non-standard browser or have some unusual setup.

Comment: are you sure the element isn't 100px wide  - as well as 100% ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How many items have the class `myElement`? Consider using an `id`, not a `class`, as getting the width of two elements is not really possible (or logically understandable IMO).

I made a little demo, and for me, it outputs the width in pixels for a single `span` element with a width of `100%` (for me, it alerts something around `400`): http://jsfiddle.net/LqpNK/3/.

By the way, `<span>` element's can't have a set width or height, so setting their width and height does you no good. Instead, display them as a `block` element (so just replace `<span>` with `<div>`, or add `display: block;` to the CSS of `.myElement`).

Answer (score 8):

.css('width') should return 100%, however .width() should (as described here http://api.jquery.com/width/) return a unit-less pixel amount. I created a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/yxCav/

Answer (score 8):

Maybe

```
elt.getBoundingClientRect().width
```

Comment: There's an interesting caveat to this: if there's a transform on the element, this returns the _displayed_ width, while jQuery returns the element's actual width. ie, if you `rotateY(90deg)` a 100px^2 box, the above returns `0`, while jQuery returns `100`.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
document.getElementById().offsetWidth;
```

Answer (score 4):

From the jQuery documentation on [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

> The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width() method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

So it returns pixels if the pixel width is defined, but you are defining the width in %

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced like in this post: [jQuery width() not returning correct value on a div with generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208951/jquery-width-not-returning-correct-value-on-a-div-with-generated-content). If the div is not displayed earlier or are loading content dynamically, the .width() function returns the percentage value, but till the element is fully loaded the same .width() function will return width in pixels.