# HTML DOM alerting style.width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get element width in px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525049/get-element-width-in-px)

How can I find the width of divA? This code brings up an empty alert popup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function DisplayResult(){
    width = document.getElementById("divA").style.width;
    alert(width);
}
var widthFinder = {   
    find: DisplayResult
};
widthFinder.find();

</script>

<div id="divA">Alert this string's length in pixels</div>
```

EDIT:

This now alerts "null". Still not quite what im hoping for.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function DisplayResult(){
var width = $("#divA").width();
alert(width);
}
var widthFinder = {   
find: DisplayResult
};
widthFinder.find();

</script>

<div id="divA" style="display:inline; width:100%;">Alert this string's length in pixels</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless you have a style for `divA`'s width, Javascript is correctly alerting `""`. You'll need to use some other method (probably something via jQuery) to find the actual computed width of the div, as opposed to finding its CSS style for width.

Comment: @Nightfirecat, Thanks are there any jQuery statements you would recommend?

Comment: Since you've added the JQuery lib to the document's head, I've retagged your question to include `jquery`, which will bring another wave of answers if the current ones don't suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is set to be executed before the DOM is ready, hence why it doesn't find any element and returns a `null` value.

```
function DisplayResult(){ //declared function in the document's head, ok
    var width = $("#divA").width();
    alert(width);
}

$(document).ready(function(){ //function calls here, when the DOM is ready
    var widthFinder = {   
    find: DisplayResult()
    };
    widthFinder.find();
});
```

I've wrapped your function call inside the [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event which prevent the code from being executed before the DOM is ready. I've also added `()` to the `DisplayResult()` to ensure that it's being interpreted as a function call.

Try out this [***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/gd2gd/2/) example.

Comment: It works! Very nice Fabricio! You once again impress me incredibly. Thank you for helping me so much tonight. I really appreciate it

Comment: It's no prob :) Time to call it a night though, sleep well :P

Answer (score 2):

you could always use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
alert($("#divA").width());
```

or you could try this way and keep the width of diva stored in a variable

```
var width = $("#divA").width());
alert(width);
```

Comment: Hmmm This is alerting "null", then killing the rest of my script.

Comment: Make sure you've included the JQuery lib in your document. :)

Comment: @FabricioMatte, thanks to you earlier today I already have haha. And Css Tube your second example still returns "null" but it isn't killing my script anymore

Comment: Wait a minute, do you need to include different JQuery libraries for different types of jQuery calls?

Comment: Nope, unless you're using a JQuery plugin or the [UI plugins](http://jqueryui.com). Including just the JQuery lib will do for this (the one I linked in your other question). :P Also, check the linked answer in your question's comments, adding a `div { width:100%; }` to your css seems to fix this.

Comment: Good to know. And yeah I saw that in there and added it to my code, but I am still getting null. I also though it might be a problem that my div is display:none but that doesnt seem to be it either

Comment: Guess I'm running out of ideas for tonight, but I made a quick fiddle with the `divA` and @CssTube's code: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gd2gd/). Guess you can start from there and check where your code breaks. :P

Comment: Change the `$("#stringID")` to `$("#divA")`. The `#` is the JQuery ID selector. :P [JQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) support basically all of the CSS selectors.

Comment: Guess I'm borrowing too much of Css Tube's reply, time to submit my own.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, what you want can be easily done & there are two ways for this:

- One, as already answered you could do

  `alert($("#divA").width());`

This would return the width as a single number. If the width is 600px, it would return 600.

- Secondly you can use [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) property to get width like

  `alert($("#divA").css("width"));`

This would return the width exactly as given in the css file. If the width is 600 px, then it would return 600px not just 600.

Comment: Im using alert($("#divA").width()); when the width is 100%. It is returning the length of the div 90% of the time. But right now its returning 100 (because of the 100%, 50 when %50), and I can't figure out why. gopi, could you explain this for me?

Answer (score 1):

For the non-Jquery version. Try delaying the function call after the `onload` happens. For example:

```
window.onload = function(){
    DisplayResult();
}
```