# How to get width of element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, width

I am trying to compare width of one element  with  "100%" with the below code. I wrote this code but did not work. Width of element is `100%` . Please advice

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].offsetWidth ==="100%") {
    clearInterval(r1);
    clearInterval(r2);
    clearInterval(r3);
}
```

Comment: oh Sorry. I think best way to check is if the parent width is same to this element. I dont think you can do that 100% as a string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525049/get-element-width-in-px

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is working correctly, but `offsetWidth` returns the physical pixel width of the element on the screen. Since you're doing a strict equality comparison using `===`, the `if()` block **never** evaluates to true; `offsetWidth` returns an integer to start, and will never append the `%` value.

For example, see this [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3t0fnzwz/) -- the `<input />`'s value becomes an integer.

If you absolutely need to have the width as a percentage value, you'll need to access the element's CSS definitions using the [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property as follows:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].style.width;
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3t0fnzwz/1/)

Ultimately, your `if()` block will become:

```
if( document.getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].style.width == '100%' ) 
{
    clearInterval(r1);
    clearInterval(r2);
    clearInterval(r3);
}
```